# Check Permission at Android Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-camera, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I am writing a graphical program in eclipse IDE and compiling with 23 api version, minSdkVersion="11" and that's important for me to keep targetSdkVersion="16".
I have to use device camera in one of my activities (DarjActivity). All things work OK, but since I tried to improve my codes to support permissions of android marshmallow (api 23), so added Check_Permission class that caused for some errors. Please guide me in that confusing problem!
Thanks with regards.

DarjActivity class:

```
private void selectImage() {
    final CharSequence[] items = { "camera", "gallery",
        "cancel" };

  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(DarjActivity.this);
  builder.setTitle("capture photo");
  builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
        boolean result=Check_Permission.checkPermission(DarjActivity.this);

        if (items[item].equals("camera")) {
       //    userChoosenTask="Take Photo";
           if(result);
               Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

        } else if (items[item].equals("gallery")) {
       //    userChoosenTask="Choose from Library";
           if(result);

           Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "select"),2);

        } else if (items[item].equals("cancel")) {
            dialog.dismiss();
      }
    }    
  });
  builder.show();
}
```

Check_Permission class:

```
package com.codegostarNiloo.negar;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;

public class Check_Permission  {
   public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA = 123;

   public static boolean checkPermission(final Context context)
   {
       int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
       if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
//         if(currentAPIVersion>=Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
       {
          if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission((Activity) context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
               if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
                   AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                   alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                   alertBuilder.setTitle("Check Permission");
                   alertBuilder.setMessage("pleas let this applicathion to use your device camera");
                   alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                      @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                           ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
                       }
                   });
                   AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
                   alert.show();

               } else {
                   ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
               }
              return false;
           } else {
               return true;
           }
       } else {
           return true;
       }
   }
}
```

Here at Check_Permission class, the (checkSelfPermission) , (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale) and (requestPermissions) methods occurs errors.
For first parameter of them, I placed (Activity) context, Context context, context, this.Activity, Activity.this, DarjActivity and ext. I updated and replaced some android-support-v4.jar files in bin folder.

AndroidManifest permissions:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"></uses-feature>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"></uses-feature>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

Comment: Ignoring any errors in your code, this is wasted work if you refuse to move your `targetSdkVersion` up. Runtime permissions are only available when you target API 23 and above. Why can't you change your target version?

Comment: What kind of error occurred? Please be more specific

Comment: @ 0X0nosugar (error):
The method checkSelfPermission(Activity, String) is undefined for the type ContextCompat
The method shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Activity, String) is undefined for the type ActivityCompat

Comment: @ Tanis.7x : I have improved my target and build target version to 23 and the errors are there, yet !! :(

Answer (score 0):

Step 1.

First implement ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback in your activity

```
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 1;
    private static final String FRAGMENT_DIALOG = "dialog";
```

Step 2  Override Method

```
    @Override
     public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull           String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
{
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION:
            if (permissions.length != 1 || grantResults.length != 1) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error on requesting camera permission.");
            }
            if (grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.camera_permission_not_granted,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            // No need to start camera here; it is handled by onResume
            break;
    }
}


@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

       //   Do whatever you want to do after the permission granted.


    } else if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
        ConfirmationDialogFragment
                .newInstance(R.string.camera_permission_confirmation,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                        REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION,
                        R.string.camera_permission_not_granted)
                .show(getSupportFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_DIALOG);
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
    }



}
```

Step 3 Write a dialog fragment to ask for the permission - 
 public static class ConfirmationDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
    {

```
    private static final String ARG_MESSAGE = "message";
    private static final String ARG_PERMISSIONS = "permissions";
    private static final String ARG_REQUEST_CODE = "request_code";
    private static final String ARG_NOT_GRANTED_MESSAGE = "not_granted_message";

    public static ConfirmationDialogFragment newInstance(@StringRes int message,
                                                         String[] permissions, int requestCode, @StringRes int notGrantedMessage) {
        ConfirmationDialogFragment fragment = new ConfirmationDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_MESSAGE, message);
        args.putStringArray(ARG_PERMISSIONS, permissions);
        args.putInt(ARG_REQUEST_CODE, requestCode);
        args.putInt(ARG_NOT_GRANTED_MESSAGE, notGrantedMessage);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Bundle args = getArguments();
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setMessage(args.getInt(ARG_MESSAGE))
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                String[] permissions = args.getStringArray(ARG_PERMISSIONS);
                                if (permissions == null)
                                {
                                    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                                }
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                                        permissions, args.getInt(ARG_REQUEST_CODE));
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                        args.getInt(ARG_NOT_GRANTED_MESSAGE),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        })
                .create();
    }

}
```

Step 4 Always check on onResume() for camera permission

```
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) 
   {
       // Do whatever you want to do if permission granted
    } 
   else if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
        ConfirmationDialogFragment
                .newInstance(R.string.camera_permission_confirmation,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                        REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION,
                        R.string.camera_permission_not_granted)
                .show(getSupportFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_DIALOG);
       } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]           {   Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                     REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
    }
```

Hope it helps !!

Comment: Thanks for your help. but, I can't implement ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback in my DarjActivity because that occur error in eclipse (ActivityCompat cannot be resolved to a type) and gives quick fix: Create interface ActivityCompat. 1-Please write how to implement that and it's imports, please??    2-Are there the first and second steps in my DarjActivity or i have to create a new class?

Answer (score 0):

Or just use a simple library like [PermissionsDispatcher](https://github.com/hotchemi/PermissionsDispatcher) or [Dexter](https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter) or [EasyPermissions](https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions) or many many [others](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Managing-Runtime-Permissions-with-PermissionsDispatcher). Why do you need to pollute your code with permissions handling?

Comment: and what for eclipse, dear?!